# Send BroadCast on Long Press of Power Button

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to send BroadcastReceiver to my application on the long click of power button even if the device is lock state. Till now I try various action for this such as

```
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" >
            </action>
```

in my  but they not giving a good effect .My BroadcastReciever is only Working in the case when user turn off the device.
Please help me to sort out this problem .
Thanks

Comment: your question is not clear to me. this xml-snippet doesn't show much.

Comment: I want to do some task in my app if user long press on Power button .So I want to send a broadcast message on long press of power button .I there any way to this task? this xml are the tag in my reciever in manifest

Comment: well, how does your BroadCastReceiver look in your code? something like: activity.sendBroadcast(new Intent("mFragmentBroadcast"));

Comment: No I just register my broadcast in my manifest and make a class extends BroadCastReceiver and in onReceive() method of BroadCastReceiver  class I want to show toast if user long press the power button

Answer (score 2):

Add Intent filter:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);

BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MYBCR();
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

Your Broadcast Receiver:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)){
        Log.d("tag", "system dialog close");
    }
}
```

This works fine for me and it also listens to every system dialogs.
If you want to listen only to long press of power button, it is possible with Service and didn't find anything with broadcast receiver after going through the developer's guide.

Here is how I did with Service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

mLinear = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()) {

        //home or recent button
        public void onCloseSystemDialogs(String reason) {
            if ("globalactions".equals(reason)) {
                Log.d("tag", "Long press on power button");
            } else if ("homekey".equals(reason)) {
                //home key pressed
            } else if ("recentapps".equals(reason)) {
                // recent apps button clicked
            }
        }

    };



    mLinear.setFocusable(true);

    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.test, mLinear);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    //params

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            1,
            1,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wm.addView(mView, params);
}
```

You will need a Layout, and make sure its a linear layout and that's it.
You will be able to listen power long press even if screen is locked.

Hope this will help.